error sending invitation via email with supabase
I have some error sending invitation via email in supabase, using:
const supabase = createClient(
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL ?? "",
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVICE_ROLE_KEY ?? "",
  {
    auth: {
      autoRefreshToken: false,
      persistSession: false,
    },
  }
)

supabase.auth.admin
  .inviteUserByEmail(email)
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result.error)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.message)
  })
  }

the error loging is the next one:
AuthApiError: Error inviting user
    at handleError (fetch.js:74:11)
    at async _handleRequest (fetch.js:117:9)
    at async _request (fetch.js:99:18)
    at async GoTrueAdminApi.inviteUserByEmail (GoTrueAdminApi.js:60:20)

all this is executing in the server side, with next-actions.
I want to send invitations via email using supabase api.
